# New siunitx font specifications

Tags: fonts, siunitx, sans-serif

For personal reasons, I like when my paper is written in sans font while my math and units are written in serif. I recently updated to version 3 of the `siunitx` package and have no idea of how to reset the unit font to serif.

The command I use to set the default font is

```
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
```

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\usepackage{siunitx}
    \sisetup{mode = math, reset-text-family = true  }
\begin{document}

\qty{15}{mm}

\end{document}
```

And here's my output.[image]

Whilst my desired output is: [image]

Thank you.

Comment: Postponing execution of `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}` until *after* `\begin{document}` gets the job done. Not sure why, though.

Comment: @Mico That's interesting, never thought of changing the order. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to reverse an automatic setting change here:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
\AtBeginDocument{\sisetup{unit-font-command = \mathrm}}
\begin{document}
\qty{15}{mm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. Also, it keeps the sintaxis I prefer for my documents, so it's great.

Answer (score 3):

As Mico suggests in comments, you can postpone resetting `\familydefault` until after `siunitx` has made its decision.

Another way is to use text mode.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\sisetup{mode = text, text-font-command=\rmfamily }

\begin{document}

A length \qty{15}{mm} is specified

\end{document}
```

but this might have other issues.

The other way seems to be

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}\normalfont}

\sisetup{mode = math}

\begin{document}

A length \qty{15}{mm} is specified

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It works wonderfully, thanks.